# NullPointerException, can I use throws because I "expect" code might crash because of NullPointerException?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Can I declare my method with throws when code in method body might crash because of NullPointerException

I have code like `a.getB().getC()` inside this method

**Edit:**

[Catching nullpointerexception in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146339/catching-nullpointerexception-in-java/15146645#15146645)

I have tried with sample code,

```
class B {
    public void methodB() {}
}

class A {
    public void methodA(B b) throws NullPointerException {
        b.methodB();
    }
}

@Test
public void test_null_pointer() {
    boolean thrown1 = false;
    boolean thrown2 = false;
    A a = new A();

    try {
        B b = new B();
        a.methodA(b);
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        thrown1 = true;
    }

    try {
        a.methodA(null);
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        thrown2 = true;
    }

    assertFalse(thrown1);
    assertTrue(thrown2);
}
```

Test has succeeded.

Comment: Have you tried ?

Comment: Can I have an answer

Comment: Please go through these two pages - 
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is not recommended to catch, but you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15146645/5156075

Answer (score 1):

Do your method throw the exception?

```
public static boolean getC() throws Exception{
    if(Some Condition)
        throw new Exception("Some Error");
    else
        return true;
}
```

or

```
public static boolean getC() throws Exception{
    try{
        ... Do Something ...
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e
    }
}
```

---

If it do, you can catch the exception when the method throw the exception back.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        boolean isOK = getC(); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Optional

```
public YourObjectC getC(){
YOurObjectA a = new YourObjectA();
Optional<YourObjectC> opt = Optional.ofNullable(a)
                                    .map(YOurObjectA::getB)
                                    .map(YourObjectB::getC);

return opt.orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);

}
```

Method will return object C but if object is null will throw Null Pointer exc

Answer (score 0):

You should not.

If this may be null, you must verify and apply your business rules in this case. Otherwise, I think is a good practice you to check if a **must have** parameter is null and then you throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. You can describe this behavior on your Javadoc, for instance. But to declare a `method throws` is useless.